# calling an async function inside for loop in JavaScript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop

I want to call an async function inside for loop

```js
function test(req,res){
 //somelogic part here
 
 async function create(data){
 //logic part here
 }
 
 for( var value in values){
  // some codeing part here
  await create(data);
  }
}
```

I am getting this error

```
uncaughtException: await is only valid in async function
```

then I can't call an async function inside For loop.
I know it is written like this  but is there any possible way I can call an async function inside for loop

```
for await (var value in values)
```

Comment: put for loop inside `async` function. Also, error clearly states that. It will work inside async only

Comment: Unless `create` is returning a value I see no reason to use `async/await` here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `async` in front of function test.

`async function test(req, res) {…`

If you want to `await` a promise, then the function that's using `await` needs to be `async` function.

Comment: its saying await is only valid in async function

Comment: Unless you had brackets in wrong place, function test contains function create and the for loop. If that's correct, then making test an async function will let you use await inside for loop which reside under function test.

Answer (score 4):

Hi As I understood your concern I would suggest to use .map() function which is very useful in this type of case.

```
async function create(data) {
   // Create user logic here
}
const usernames = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3'];
const createdUsers = usernames.map(async (val) => {
    const user = await create();
    return user;
});

await Promise.all(createdUsers);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap and create new function inside another function isn't a good ideal. You can move function create to outside like the code bellow

```
 async function create(data){
 //logic part here
 }
 
async function test(req,res){
 //somelogic part here

 for( var value in values){
  // some codeing part here
  await create(data);
  }
}
```

Or use arrow function instead

```
async function test(req,res){
 //somelogic part here
 const create = async (data) => {
 //logic part here
 }
 for( var value in values){
  // some codeing part here
  await create(data);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, why is an arrow function a good idea instead?

Answer (score 0):

If calling just an asynchronous  function is only going to part of your for loop mean you can simple push the promise returned by the asynchronous calls to an array and use promise static methods like 'all'

```
let pros= []
for(){
    pro.push(create(data));
}
Promise.all(pros).then(()=> {
    #implement rest or resolve another promise
})
```

Please refer..
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with your `create` function, but with your `test` function. The scope where you **call** the `await` syntax, needs to be `async`. Therefore, your scope here is `test`.

Simply update your code to the following;

```js
/*vv --> async*/
async function test(req, res) {
  console.log("test is called");

  async function create(to) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(Date.now()), to);
    });
  }

  const values = {
    a: 1e3,
    b: 2e3,
    c: 3e3
  };

  for (var value in values) {
    // some codeing part here
    const to = values[value];
    const result = await create(to);
    console.log("result:", result);
  }

  return 1;
}

(async() => {
  const res = await test();
  console.log("done");
})();
```

Comment: i tried this too still getting same error `error: uncaughtException: await is only valid in async function`

Comment: @Vikas Then the issue is **when** you call the `test` function. Is it scoped in an async? I have updated the code to provide you a brief example with your code model.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little confusing because there doesn't appear to be any reason to `async/await` - `create` doesn't appear to return any data so the `aync/await` seems redundant, and you can probably remove it.

If, however, `create` does return a value, and you want to wait until all the values have been returned before you continue, create an array of function calls and then use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait until the promises returned from `create` have resolved.

```js
// `create` returns a promise that resolves
// after two seconds
function create(data){
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(data), 2000);
  });
}


async function test(req,res) {
 const values = [1, 2, 3, 4];

 // Create an array of promises
 const arr = values.map(el => create(el));

 // And use Promise.all to wait to resolve them
 const output = await Promise.all(arr);
 console.log(output);
}

test();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the `Promise` in the `for loop` then it will get a total of every responses time in every iteration. So I'm suggesting the `Promise.all` for that.

```
async func() {
    let arr = [];

    for(var value in values){
        arr.push(create(data));
    }

    let createdArr = await Promise.all(arr);

    // Using createdArr, you can get all waited responses
}
```

In here it will get only the most responding time, not the total. All `Promises` run at the same time.