# How to call an async function inside for loop in JavaScript / node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongoose, async-await

I have used async function inside the for loop, but the result is still not as expected, please check it for me.
Here is my code:

```
      var labelCategory = await Label.find({is_deleted: false, datasetId: id}); //Array of labels with the same datasetId

      var arrayLabel = [];

      for await (const label of labelCategory) {
        
        var labelId = label._id;

        var dataLabel = {
          "labelId": "",
          "labelName": "",
          "totalImage": ""
        }

        await Image.countDocuments({ "labels.labelId": labelId, "datasetId": id }, function (err, count) {

          dataLabel["labelId"] = labelId;
          dataLabel["labelName"] = label.labelName;
          dataLabel["totalImage"] = count;
        
          arrayLabel.push(dataLabel);
        });
      }

      console.log(arrayLabel);
      res.send({"dataLabel": arrayLabel })
```

Every time I run this code, I get different results. Since I have all 68 images (22 dogs, 24 cats, 24 pandas) with the same datasetId, the result is what I expected as follows:

```
{
    "dataLabel": [
        {
            "labelId": "6234363e406b5e0bd4f9bb14",
            "labelName": "dogs",
            "totalImage": 22
        },
        {
            "labelId": "6234364c406b5e0bd4f9bb1b",
            "labelName": "cats",
            "totalImage": 24
        },
        {
            "labelId": "62343660406b5e0bd4f9bb23",
            "labelName": "pandas",
            "totalImage": 24
        }
    ]
}
```

But I don't know if I called the async function inside the loop correctly, so sometimes I run this code and it produces the following output:

```
{
    "dataLabel": [
        {
            "labelId": "6234364c406b5e0bd4f9bb1b",
            "labelName": "cats",
            "totalImage": 24
        },
        {
            "labelId": "6234364c406b5e0bd4f9bb1b",
            "labelName": "cats",
            "totalImage": 24
        },
        {
            "labelId": "62343660406b5e0bd4f9bb23",
            "labelName": "pandas",
            "totalImage": 24
        }
    ]
}
```

Please take a look. Thanks you so much

Comment: _for await_?  Never seen that before.  Is labelCategory an array?  Why not _foreach_?

Comment: @zipzit: Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172827/calling-an-async-function-inside-for-loop-in-javascript-node-js

Comment: Oops. Right you are. [for…of loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement). Thx.

Comment: Please check where am I wrong? Thanks

Comment: When you ‘console.log(labelCategory)’  are the results as expected?  Also if you remove _await_ after _for_ does that work better?  You only need await callout  for server requests

Comment: Don’t pass callback for this function `await Image.countDocuments(`

Comment: @hoangdv: Oh may be you are right. But if i dont pass callback, how can I get count? Please correct me?

Comment: I've tried it many times, i think it ok now. Thanks

Comment: Do the same way what you did with `var labelCategory=`